# Shared resource management system

Tags: web-apps, reservation

We're looking for a web-based software to manage resources of our company, like projectors, cars and meetings rooms.

Must have features:

- Users can book a type of resources for a period of time
- Admins/resource owners/managers can accept or reject requests
- Users get email notification when the state of their request (or booking) changes (accepted/rejected/modified)

Nice to haves:

- Customizable/open source
- Various reports about usage of the managed resources
- Automatic suggestions for equal usage of resources (to avoid the situation when one car has run about 120 000 km and another one has run only 10 000 km)
- Settable maintenance periods for resources (when the resource is unavailable for users)
- Sharing resources between users (two people can get the same car to go to the same city on the same day) (merging requests)

On the technology side, we would prefer Java and Linux but anything else could be good.

User management can take place "locally" inside the application. LDAP/Active Directory support is not required currently.

Comment: I think you would need to create a specific Database environment for this. MySQL with PHP FrontEnd should work but has a lot of work. I remember having such a system in School for renting Tech-Stuff. I would be interested in a official Solution though.

Comment: @YoshiBotX: Yeah, we could write an in-house app but I think it would be cheaper to use an existing solution if it exists. It seems a common corporate problem to me, so I hope there are existing solutions.

Comment: We use Google Apps to manage our conference room reservations; you just "invite" the conference room when you create the calendar invitation. I think we have it configured to automatically allocate the conference room to you if it's available, and it notifies you if you're trying to book it for a time that it's already reserved.

Comment: @rob it was an in-house solution or Google Apps gives you a solution (we don't have the Apps, but I could ask).

Answer (score 2):

### Booked Scheduler

The most flexible free and open source software for shared resource management is definitely [Booked Scheduler](https://www.bookedscheduler.com/free-trial-signup). You can download it and host it yourself, or book a 10 USD/month hosting service from the developer.

It provides all the features you listed, with the exception of "automatic suggestions for equal usage of resources" and "merging requests" (such as ride sharing). But these can probably be added with a custom plugin.

It's not Java but PHP though.

### Other open source resource scheduling software

I have recently done a survey of all free / open source resource scheduling and booking applications. None of them is in Java unfortunately. See [the full list of what I found](https://edgeryders.eu/t/6629).